# fallocate failing inside my docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run a script inside my Linux Ubuntu 14.10 Docker container which uses the `fallocate` command like so:

```
fallocate -l 10M 10meg
```

However, when I run this script, and even when I run the command when I have ssh'd into my container, I get the following error:

```
root@~$>> fallocate -l 10M 10meg
fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported
```

Any ideas why this is failing inside my container?

Answer (score 5):

at the time of writing, [`fallocate()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) syscall is not supported by [Union FS](http://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#how-does-a-docker-image-work), the filesystem used by Docker.
You can either use `truncate` as follows (recommended):

```
truncate -s 10M 10meg
```

or `dd` (expensive):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=10meg bs=1M count=10
```